# msgbox error while threading , GUI blocks

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt5, qthread

I have a problem while executing the following gui. it works normally if there's no msgbox, but when there is a mesbox it blocks. any idea why the gui blocks when there is message. thank you

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import threading
import time
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 26))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)
        self.pushButton.pressed.connect(self.threadingc)      
    def calculation(self):
        for i in range(10):
            time.sleep(1)
            print(i)
        msg = QtWidgets.QMessageBox()
        msg.setInformativeText('Finish')
        msg.exec_()   
    def threadingc(self):
        x=threading.Thread(target=self.calculation)
        x.start()
    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))
import sys
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Please avoid creating questions that are very similar to others posted by you. I just noticed your [other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64766901/threading-pyqt5-app-make-the-gui-responsive-while-calculating), after answering this. I'll leave it here as I believe it answers your question, but I suggest you to remove the other one as it also can be answered by this (and there's already plenty posts similar to that here on StackOverflow).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Any** access to UI elements is only allowed from within the main Qt thread. Note that *access* means not only reading/writing widget properties, but also creation; any attempt to do so from other threads results in graphical issues or incosistent behavior in the best case, and a crash in the worst (and more common) case.

The only correct way to do so is to use a QThread with (possibly) custom signals: this allows Qt to correctly queue signals and react to them when it can actually process them.

The following is a *very* simple situation that doesn't require creating a QThread subclass, but consider that this is just for *educational* purposes.

```
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    # ...

    def calculation(self):
        for i in range(10):
            time.sleep(1)
            print(i)

    def showMessage(self):
        msg = QtWidgets.QMessageBox()
        msg.setInformativeText('Finish')
        msg.exec_()   
        self.pushButton.setEnabled(True)

    def threadingc(self):
        self.pushButton.setEnabled(False)
        self.thread = QtCore.QThread()
        # override the `run` function with ours; this ensures that the function
        # will be executed in the new thread
        self.thread.run = self.calculation
        self.thread.finished.connect(self.showMessage)
        self.thread.start()
```

Please consider the following important aspects:

- I had to disable the pushbutton, otherwise it would be possible to create a new thread while the previous one still executing; this will create a problem, since overwriting `self.thread` will cause python to try to garbage collect (*delete*) the previous thread while running, which is a *very bad* thing;
- a possible solution to this is to create the thread with a parent, which is usually done with a simple `QThread(self)`, but that's not possible in your case because Qt objects can accept only other Qt objects as their parent, while in your case `self` would be a `Ui_MainWindow` instance (which is a basic python object);
- the above point is an important issue, because you're trying to implement your program starting from a `pyuic` generated file, which should **never** be done: those files are intended to be left as they are without *any* manual modification, and used only as imported modules; read more about this topic on the official guidelines about [using Designer](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html); also note that trying to mimic the behavior of those files is useless, as normally leads to great confusion about object structure;
- you could theoretically add a reference to a qt object (for example, by adding `self.mainWindow = MainWindow` in the `setupUi()` function) and create the thread with that reference (`thread = QThread(self.mainWindow)`), or add the thread to a persistent list (`self.threads = []`, again in the `setupUi()`), but due to the above point I strongly discourage you to do so;

Finally, a more *correct* implementation of your code would require you to generate again the ui file, *leave it as it is* and do something like the following example; note that I added a *very basic* exception implementation that also shows how to correctly interact with custom signals.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from mainwindow import Ui_MainWindow
import time

class Calculation(QtCore.QThread):
    error = QtCore.pyqtSignal(object)
    def run(self):
        for i in range(10):
            time.sleep(1)
            print(i)
            try:
                10 / 0
            except Exception as e:
                self.error.emit(e)
                break


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.pushButton.pressed.connect(self.threadingc)

    def showMessage(self):
        msg = QtWidgets.QMessageBox()
        msg.setInformativeText('Finish')
        msg.exec_()   

    def threadingc(self):
        # create the thread with the main window as a parent, this is possible 
        # since QMainWindow also inherits from QObject, and this also ensures
        # that python will not delete it if you want to start another thread
        thread = Calculation(self)
        thread.finished.connect(self.showMessage)
        thread.error.connect(self.showError)
        thread.start()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainWindow = MainWindow()
    mainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

In the above case, the ui file was processed using the following command (assuming that the ui is named "mainwindow.ui", obviously):

```
pyuic mainwindow.ui -o mainwindow.py
```

Comment: Thank you for your response it's so interesting and i've learned a lot of it. on thing imagine in the calculation.run i have an exception or a lot of exceptions and inside that exception i want to see a msgbox how can i do that. thanks

Comment: @Yakoub see the update

Comment: that would help a lot thanks