# threading a class with arguments pyqt5

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt5, qthread

In the following code I've tried to thread the calculation class that needs x as an argument, the thread works perfectly when there's no x. but once i put an argument the things missed up, can i know why?

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from mainwindow2 import Ui_Form
import time

class Calculation(QtCore.QThread):
    def __init__(self,x):
        super().__init__()
        self.x = x
    def run(self):
        for i in range(10):
            if i!=5:
                time.sleep(1)
                print(i+self.x)
        
class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_Form):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.pushButton.pressed.connect(self.threadingc)

    def threadingc(self):
        # create the thread with the main window as a parent, this is possible 
        # since QMainWindow also inherits from QObject, and this also ensures
        # that python will not delete it if you want to start another thread
        self.pushButton.setEnabled(False)
        thread = Calculation(5)
        thread.start()
        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainWindow = MainWindow()
    mainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

mainwindow2

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(400, 300)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 110, 93, 28))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Form", "PushButton"))
```

Comment: share your ui_form too

Comment: @Shoaib Mirzaei  done

Comment: I am not sure what you want to do with your code. but your code does not have definition for `self.error` and it's working fine. you have to add `self.run()` to `__init__` function of the class `Calculation`

Comment: @ShoaibMirzaei for me it doesn't work at all. i run  the code and than it blocks

Comment: what do you expect as output? when I run it, it prints `5,6,7,8,9` and it gives error

Comment: Please, carefully read the previous [answer given to you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64769327/msgbox-error-while-threading-gui-blocks) and try to understand its mechanism, don't just modify things without knowing what you're doing. For instance, as explained there, the parent (`self`) argument is **very** important if you're not setting a persistent reference to the thread (you also copied the comment about that, which makes me think that you didn't actually read or understand it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide the parent variable to the thread.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

import time


class Calculation(QtCore.QThread):
    
    def __init__(self, parent, x):
        # I have added the parent variable.
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.x = x
    
    def run(self):
        for i in range(10):
            if i != 5:
                time.sleep(1)
                print(i + self.x)

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_Form):
    ...
    
    def threadingc(self):
        # You need to provide a reference to the gui or make the thread a class variable.
        thread = Calculation(self, 5)
        thread.start()
        # If you don't provide a parent or make the thread a class variable the function scope will
        # end here and the thread variable will be terminated.


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainWindow = MainWindow()
    mainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```